# Syntax error in constraints with ampl on a minimization problem

Tags: ampl

I have a syntax error in my ampl code that I can't understand. Here is the code:

```
set J := {1..4};
set I := {1..2};
set L := {1..3};

param A{J};

var p {I,J} >= 0;
var z;


maximize profit: z;

#constraints
s.t. worse_outcome:
z <= A[1] * p[1,1] + A[2] * (p[1,2]+p[1,3]) + p[1,4] + p[2,4]
z <= A[1] * p[1,1] + A[2] * (p[1,2]+p[1,4]) + A[4] * p[2,3]
z <= A[1] * p[1,1] + A[2] * (p[1,3]+p[1,4]) + A[4] * p[2,2]
z <= A[3] * p[2,1] + A[4] * (p[2,2]+p[2,3]) + p[1,4] + p[2,4]
z <= A[3] * p[2,1] + A[4] * (p[2,2]+p[2,4]) + A[2] * p[1,3]
z <= A[3] * p[2,1] + A[4] * (p[2,3]+p[2,4]) + A[2] * p[1,2];

s.t. money: sum {i in I} {j in J} p[i,j] <= 100;

#data
param A :=
1   2.5
2   1.5
3   1.66667
4   3
```

And here is the error message:
syntax error
context:   >>> z  <<< <= A[1] * p[1,1] + A[2] * (p[1,2]+p[1,4]) + A[4] * p[2,3]

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're trying to specify six different constraints there within the syntax of a single constraint. That won't work.

Try instead:

```
s.t. worse_outcome_1: z <= A[1] * p[1,1] + A[2] * (p[1,2]+p[1,3]) + p[1,4] + p[2,4];
s.t. worse_outcome_2: z <= A[1] * p[1,1] + A[2] * (p[1,2]+p[1,4]) + A[4] * p[2,3];
s.t. worse_outcome_3: z <= A[1] * p[1,1] + A[2] * (p[1,3]+p[1,4]) + A[4] * p[2,2];
s.t. worse_outcome_4: z <= A[3] * p[2,1] + A[4] * (p[2,2]+p[2,3]) + p[1,4] + p[2,4];
s.t. worse_outcome_5: z <= A[3] * p[2,1] + A[4] * (p[2,2]+p[2,4]) + A[2] * p[1,3];
s.t. worse_outcome_6: z <= A[3] * p[2,1] + A[4] * (p[2,3]+p[2,4]) + A[2] * p[1,2];
```

If you want to specify multiple rules with a single statement, you need to do that with an indexed constraint. For instance, the first and fourth of the constraints above could be combined into something like:

```
s.t. worse_outcome_1_4{i in 1..2}: z <= A[2*i-1] * p[i,1] 
                                       + A[2*i] * (p[i,2]+p[i,3])
                                       + p[1,4] + p[2,4];
```